# Matlab error: pdelib:initmesh:LargeMesh

Tags: matlab, mesh, pde

I have a question about Matlab mesh generations:

1. How do I manage the size ofthe  mesh in Matlab?
2. What can I do to workaround this error?

Error message

```
Error using message
Error filling holes for pdelib:initmesh:LargeMesh. Floating point numbers are not
allowed as holes. They should be converted to strings.

Error in initmesh (line 135)
  fprintf(['\n' message('pdelib:initmesh:LargeMesh', ntg).getString() '\n']);

Error in pdegplot>plotTwoDGeometry (line 112)
      [p1,~,t1]=initmesh(g,'hmax',0.1,'init','on', 'MesherVersion','R2013a');

Error in pdegplot (line 73)
        hh = plotTwoDGeometry(g.geom, plotEdgeNums, plotSubLabels);

Error in test_ellips_10 (line 102)
pdegplot(model,'EdgeLabels','on','SubdomainLabels','on')
```

This Error is generated by Matlab R2015b when the following code is run:

```
% Rectangle R1
R1_x1 = 0;
R1_x2 = 3810;
R1_y1 = 0;
R1_y2 = 6800;

% Rectangle R2
R2_x1 = (3810/4);
R2_x2 = (3*3810/4);
R2_y1 = (6800+3810/4);
R2_y2 = 6800;

% Rectangle R5
R5_x1 = (3810/4);
R5_x2 = (3*3810/4);
R5_y1 = 0;
R5_y2 = -(3810/4);

% Rectangle R3
R3_x1 = (3810/2-75);
R3_x2 = (3810/2+75);
R3_y1 = (6800+3810/4+100);
R3_y2 = (6800+3810/4);

% Rectangle R4
R4_x1 = (3810/2-75);
R4_x2 = (3810/2+75);
R4_y1 = -3810/4;
R4_y2 = -(3810/4+100);

% Ellipse E1
% pdeellip(xc,yc,a,b,phi,label)
E1_xc = 3810/4;
E1_yc = 6800;
E1_a = 3810/4;
E1_b = 3810/4;
E1_phi = 0;

% Ellipse E2
% pdeellip(xc,yc,a,b,phi,label)
E2_xc = 3*3810/4;
E2_yc = 6800;
E2_a = 3810/4;
E2_b = 3810/4;
E2_phi = 0;

% Ellipse E3
% pdeellip(xc,yc,a,b,phi,label)
E3_xc = 3810/4;
E3_yc = 0;
E3_a = 3810/4;
E3_b = 3810/4;
E3_phi = 0;

% Ellipse E4
% pdeellip(xc,yc,a,b,phi,label)
E4_xc = 3*3810/4;
E4_yc = 0;
E4_a = 3810/4;
E4_b = 3810/4;
E4_phi = 0;

model = createpde(1);
% Rectangle is code 3, 4 sides,
% followed by x-coordinates and then y-coordinates
R1 = [3, 4, R1_x1,R1_x2,R1_x2, R1_x1, R1_y1, R1_y1, R1_y2, R1_y2]';
R1 = [3, 4, R1_x1,R1_x2,R1_x2, R1_x1, R1_y1, R1_y1, R1_y2, R1_y2]';
R2 = [3, 4, R2_x1,R2_x2,R2_x2, R2_x1, R2_y1, R2_y1, R2_y2, R2_y2]';
R3 = [3, 4, R3_x1,R3_x2,R3_x2, R3_x1, R3_y1, R3_y1, R3_y2, R3_y2]';
R4 = [3, 4, R4_x1,R4_x2,R4_x2, R4_x1, R4_y1, R4_y1, R4_y2, R4_y2]';
R5 = [3, 4, R5_x1,R5_x2,R5_x2, R5_x1, R5_y1, R5_y1, R5_y2, R5_y2]';
% Ellipse is code 1, center (E1_x,E1_y), First semiaxis length (strictly positive),Second semiaxis length (strictly positive),Angle in radians from x axis to first semiaxis
E1 = [4,E1_xc,E1_yc,E1_a,E1_b,E1_phi]';
E2 = [4,E2_xc,E2_yc,E2_a,E2_b,E2_phi]';
E3 = [4,E3_xc,E3_yc,E3_a,E3_b,E3_phi]';
E4 = [4,E4_xc,E4_yc,E4_a,E4_b,E4_phi]';

% Pad E1 with zeros to enable concatenation with R1
E1 = [E1;zeros(length(R1) - length(E1),1)];
E2 = [E2;zeros(length(R1) - length(E2),1)];
E3 = [E3;zeros(length(R1) - length(E3),1)];
E4 = [E4;zeros(length(R1) - length(E4),1)];

% Combine the shapes into one matrix
geom = [R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,E1,E2,E3,E4];
% Names for the  geometric objects
ns = (char('R1','R2','R3','R4','R5','E1','E2','E3','E4'));
ns = ns';
% Set formula
sf = 'R1+R2+R3+R4+R5+E1+E2+E3+E4';
% Create geometry
DL=decsg(geom,sf,ns);

% Check model
% If all elements of 0 geometry is OK
gstat=csgchk(geom);

% Include the geometry in the model
geometryFromEdges(model,DL);

% View geometry
pdegplot(model,'EdgeLabels','on','SubdomainLabels','on')
xlim('auto')
ylim('auto')
axis equal

generateMesh(model,'Hgrad',1.3,'Hmax',10,'Box','on','Init','on','jiggle','on','MesherVersion','R2013a');
pdeplot(model)
```

Comment: Mathwork's support answer that it's a bug of matlab. To fix you need to patch pdeplot: >>edit pdegplot
edit the line 112
[p1,~,t1]=initmesh(g,'hmax',0.1,'init','on', 'MesherVersion','R2013a');
change it to
[p1,~,t1]=initmesh(g,'init','on', 'MesherVersion','R2013a');

Answer (score 0):

Mathwork's support answer that it's a bug of matlab. To fix you need to patch pdeplot:

```
>>edit pdegplot
```

edit the line 112

```
[p1,~,t1]=initmesh(g,'hmax',0.1,'init','on', 'MesherVersion','R2013a');
```

change it to

```
[p1,~,t1]=initmesh(g,'init','on', 'MesherVersion','R2013a');
```